# Save variable RESULTS into tmp file to be recalled later?

Tags: macos, bash, variables, find, temporary-files

Running a script which finds a hand full of files and set *their* directories as variables. I use this script to prompt an osascript dialog box for user input which then calls the file that is similair to the user input.

Everything works. Only issue, when I run the script, it seems to take 10-15 seconds to load dialog box. If I run it again right after the first time, it loads in 2-4 seconds....

Question is:

Is there a way to load the results of my "find" variables faster? Maybe have it store the results in a **tmp folder** so the next time it runs, it can search just the txt file and put the file directories from there into the variables... (*unless they've moved, hence, then I need to do a If-Else statements?*)

```
#!/bin/sh

## READ LOCAL DIR FOR DIALOG BOX ICON
## CHANGE BACK-SLASH TO COLON (USE FOR VARIABLE IN OSASCRIPT)
dir=$(pwd)
dir=${dir//\//:}

abd="$(find ~/ -name "file.1")" 
cbd="$(find ~/ -name "file.2")"  
csd="$(find ~/ -name "file.3")" 
sad="$(find ~/ -name "file 4")" 


workout="$(osascript -e 'Tell application "System Events" to display dialog "Please enter your workout code:" with icon file "'$dir:appIcon.icns'" with title "Title_Here" buttons {"Cancel", "Ok"} default button 2 default answer ""' -e 'text returned of result' 2>/dev/null)"

if [ "$workout" = "ab" ] 
then 
  open "$abd"

elif [ "$workout" = "cb" ] 
then
  open "$cbd"

elif [ "$workout" = "cs" ] 
then
  open "$workout"

elif [ "$workout" = "sa" ] 
then
  open "$sad"

else
  exit     

fi
```

Comment: Your code seems flawed. I don't know how you can `open` the output of `find`, quoted, which might contain multiple results. Not a good idea in any way. Also, why don't you display the menu first and only do the relevant search when you know the option? That will likely cut down the wait time by a factor of four, if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: By the way, follow-up on the `find` and `open` issue I mentioned above: what you should do is `find ~ -name file.1 -exec open {} +`. Also, if you are just looking for a file named `file.1` in your home folder, you can also set the `globstar` option (`shopt -s globstar`), then use a wildcard `~/**/file.1`. I don't know if this will be faster than `find` (never done a benchmark), but it is worth a try if you are interested.

Comment: Worth nothing that the OP will have to install `bash` 4 or later to use the `globstar` option.

Comment: @4ae1e1 I'll be using `source` as that solved my dilemma :)

Comment: As a general rule, you don't want to combine languages like this. I'm pretty sure there is no reason you couldn't write a single AppleScript to do this, or do the entire thing in shell.

Comment: @chepner Can you shed some light on the idea of not combining languages? Thanks...

Comment: It's just needlessly complex. Why write code in two languages when you can write it in one?

Comment: @chepner Actually AppleScript is an exception, and this combination is pretty reasonable. Yes, you might be able to write the entire thing in AppleScript (just might), but if you've ever written AppleScript before, you'll realize it's verbose and confusing as hell and would want to minimize its presence as much as possible.

Comment: As for the entire thing in shell... I don't know. AppleScript is the bridge to the GUI world. You might be able to install some third party command line tools to act as GUI bridges (e.g., terminal-notifier which I use daily), but under the hood they are either ObjC/Swift or AppleScript. There's really no shell binding in most cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found my answer and it seems `source` does the job. For the script below to make sense, it will be complied in an application via [Platypus](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus).

If there is anyway to compress this, please share.

```
#!/bin/sh

## READ LOCAL DIR
## CHANGE BACK-SLASH TO COLON (USE FOR VARIABLE IN OSASCRIPT)
dir=$(pwd)
dir=${dir//\//:}

## REPAIR AND RELOCATE FILE FUNCTION
## RUN FUNCTION ON FIRST LOAD AND WHEN USER INPUTS [repair]
## STORES VARIABLES IN TMP FOLDER TO BE CALLED LATER
function repaird() {    
    abd="$(find ~/ -name "FILE 1")" 
    cbd="$(find ~/ -name "FILE 2")"
    csd="$(find ~/ -name "FILE 3")"
    sad="$(find ~/ -name "FILE 4")"
    app="$(find ~/ -name "FILE.app")"  
    echo "#!/bin/sh" > /tmp/VAR_LIST.sh    ##CREATE .SH FILE TO STORE VARIABLES
    echo "" >> /tmp/VAR_LIST.sh
    echo "abd='$abd'" >> /tmp/VAR_LIST.sh
    echo "cbd='$cbd'" >> /tmp/VAR_LIST.sh
    echo "csd='$csd'" >> /tmp/VAR_LIST.sh
    echo "sad='$sad'" >> /tmp/VAR_LIST.sh
    cd /tmp
    chmod +x VAR_LIST.sh; }                

## CHECK IF VAR_LIST FILE EXIST
## IF NOT THEN PROCEED TO FIND FILES AND SAVE VARIABLES TO VAR_LIST

if ls /tmp/VAR_LIST.sh* 1> /dev/null 2>&1; then
    source /tmp/VAR_LIST.sh         ## USE SOURCE TO CALL OUR VAR_LIST 
else
    repaird
fi

## USE OSASCRIPT TO CALL DIALOG BOX WITH USER INPUT    

WORKOUT="$(osascript -e 'Tell application "System Events" to display dialog "Please enter your workout code:" & "\n[ab] = Ab" & "\n[cb] = Cb" & "\n[cs] = Cs" & "\n[sa] = Sa" & "\n[repair] = Repair Directory" with icon file "'$dir:appIcon.icns'" with title "MY_TITLE" buttons {"Cancel", "Ok"} default button 2 default answer ""' -e 'text returned of result' 2>/dev/null)"

## SEE IF USERS INPUT MATCHES ANY OF THE OPTIONS BELOW
## IF NOT THEN EXIT SCRIPT

if [ "$WORKOUT" = "ab" ] 
then 
  open "$abd"; afplay ohyeah.mp3

elif [ "$WORKOUT" = "cb" ] 
then
  open "$cbd"; afplay ohyeah.mp3

elif [ "$WORKOUT" = "cs" ] 
then
  open "$csd"; afplay ohyeah.mp3

elif [ "$WORKOUT" = "sa" ] 
then
  open "$sad"; afplay ohyeah.mp3

elif [ "$WORKOUT" = "repair" ]       ## REPAIR WILL DO THE FOLLOWING
then
  rm /tmp/VAR_LIST.sh             ## RM CURRENT VAR_LIST
  repaird                        ## RUN FUNCTION <REPAIRD>
  sleep 5; open "$app" &         ## DELAY 5 SECONDS THEN OPEN SCRIPT AS BACKGROUND
  close "$app"                   ## CLOSE SCRIPT  
else                             ## SCRIPT OPENS AFTER 5 SECONDS WHICH PROMPTS
  exit                           ## USER WITH SAME 

fi
```